# Sync other folders with iCloud

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization

I know that with iCloud Drive I can sync the Desktop and Documents folder on iCloud. But I wonder if there is a way I can sync other folders on iCloud such as Applications, Photo Library, Downloads, etc.?

Comment: Every one of those folder you mentioned with the exception of /Applicatoins is synced with iCloud.  Are you having an issue where it isn't syncing?

Comment: @Allan Photo Library and Downloads are already synched? and is there is a way to sync the applications folders as well?

Comment: Go to https://www.apple.com/icloud/ - most of the marketing material is dedicated to photos.  As for syncing Applications - it's not a good idea.  If you're thinking of a way to back up your /Applications folder, this is what Time Machine is for.

Comment: @Allan Thank you. So better I delete the question?

Comment: Question is fine, we can close it as a duplicate. It will still help people whose search terms match your question to find good answers.